# Fix date strings with days and months interchanged in certain rows

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I m trying to upload some data from a csv file and find the values for date and month get interchanged.

Given below is how the data looks:

```
id,date
1001,09/10/2018
1002,20/09/2018
1003,09/05/2018
```

All of the dates are from September but as seen they are interchanged in different format. I am using the below to convert to datetime

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

Comment: What do you want your data to look like? Is the sample data given the data in the df or is it the desired output? If I just read the data as shown with ``pd.to_datetime()` it correctly displays the data with all dates being in september.

Comment: @Scotty1- What if the second row was 10/09/2018? Do you think that will still work?

Comment: @coldspeed Right, got it. Didn't think about that possibility...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas has no issues dealing with your sample data because it clearly comes in the [US notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_and_time_notation_in_the_United_States) apart from the case of `'20/09/2018'` where `20` cannot possibly be a month which pandas has no problem dealing with either.

However, if the input contains e.g. `'10/09/2018'` (as was mentioned in the comments) where it's impossible to tell day and month apart unless either the US notation is assumed or it is known beforehand that absolutely all dates are in September.

Since the latter seems to be the case, you can do

```
df['date'].map(lambda x: pd.datetime(x.year, x.day, x.month)
               if (x.month != 9) & (x.day == 9)
               else x)
```

```
0   2018-09-10
1   2018-09-20
2   2018-09-05
```

Answer (score 2):

I've figured out a neat little trick using `str.extract` and `pd.to_datetime` to do this quickly and efficiently:

```
m = df.date.str.extract(r'(?:(09)/(\d+))')[1].astype(int) > 31
df['date'] = [
    pd.to_datetime(d, dayfirst=m) for d, m in zip(df.date, m)]

     id       date
0  1001 2018-09-10
1  1002 2018-09-20
2  1003 2018-09-05
```

Comment: @coldspeed, thanks for the reply.. I am still seeing the month / date column interchanged

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Try running `df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',')`

Comment: @hellokee I don't think you're doing it right. Copy paste the code as is; and make sure the result is assigned back. Not sure I can do much more.

Comment: m = df.ref_date.str.extract(r'(?:(09)/(\d+))')[1].astype(int) > 31
df['ref_date'] = [pd.to_datetime(d, dayfirst=m) for d, m in zip(df.ref_date, m)]
df

Comment: @coldspeed, I understand and appreciate your assistance, I have pasted the code I tried running in my earlier message. Could you please have a look at that. Thanks..

Comment: @hellokee I ran exactly what you pasted (but I had to change "date" to "ref_date" in your example) and it worked for me. What is your pandas version? This is tested and working nicely on 0.23.4.